# how to bind data PropertyInfo class in Soap envelope in android

Tags: android, soap

```
List<Bean2> postdataarralist = new ArrayList<Bean2>();
postdataarralist = datasource.getAllComments();  
  InfraVisit C = new InfraVisit();
    C.setList(postdataarralist);
```

Here i am in postdataarralist  i am getting all data from Sqlite and in C.setList(postdataarralist) i am adding data.

```
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
                pi.setName("lstInfraVisit");
                pi.setValue(C);
                pi.setType(InfraVisit.class);
                request.addProperty(pi);
```

This is my code where i am tring to set value in PropertyInfo Class.

```
envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                envelope.dotNet = true;
                envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                androidHttpTransport.call(PostSOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Log.d("RESPONSEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE", androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            Log.d("RESPONSEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE222",androidHttpTransport.responseDump);
```

when i try to get Soap request then i am unable to find the Object of all data can u please suggest me where am doing wrong and how i can request for post data to server please help .

Comment: You are facing problem in sending request or get response?

Comment: in request Soap data to server actually i have to post data to server @ chandil03

Comment: What is the problem in current code?

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/RvMfkfRWP4dTuwN8iCv4hP  am getting this in Soap envalape while i have to send  http://paste.ofcode.org/ey3wms8k7AJ7WWZtkYPHud like this

Comment: Do you know what response server is returning?

Comment: its Exception Coming SoapFault e null

Comment: can you post your exact code you are using?

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/36h9beKbDTUCVhQjsgPdfZj  this code i have tried and catch (SoapFault e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }  in this line i am getting e=null

Comment: Can you show your logcat also?

Comment: seee no Logcat is there   that excetion coming in doibackground

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84448/discussion-between-research-development-and-chandil03).